Is there a way to Add Flag enum to each other without knowing the exact enum type?
I'm finding a way to do sth like this in C#:
// giving eTankComponents is an [Flags] enum

[Flags]
public enum eTankComponents
{
     Empty = 0,
     Barrel = 1,
     wheels = 2,
}

Type enumType = Type.GetType("eTankComponents");
object emptyTank = Enum.Parse(enumType, "Empty");
object tankWithBarrel = Enum.AddFlag(emptyTank, enumType, Enum.Parse(enumType, "Barrel"));
object fullTank = Enum.AddFlag(tankWithBarrel, enumType, Enum.Parse(enumType, "wheels"));`

Is there any Method in c# to do sth like Enum.AddFlag
searched online and found nothing.

What does sth mean?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Well, Enum.Parse(enumType, "Barrel, wheels") will give you the combined value. But it's not clear to me why you'd need to do that. Are you trying to use reflection to update an object of an unknown type?

@RichardDeeming yes. I'm trying to make an editor with nodes outputs all kinds of Types in the Assemblies to each other. So An FlagEnumNode is designed to output an object enumValueObj of any enum which marked with attribute [Flags].

You can get the underlying values using Convert.ToInt64 and use bitwise OR on them. Int64 is the largest underlying value type that an enum can have, and this will work for enums with smaller underlying value types too.
Then you can use ToObject to get the enum value from the underlying value.
Type enumType = Type.GetType("eTankComponents");
var barrel = Enum.Parse(enumType, "Barrel");
var wheels = Enum.Parse(enumType, "Wheels");
var combined = Convert.ToInt64(barrel) | Convert.ToInt64(wheels);

Console.WriteLine(Enum.ToObject(enumType, combined));


"Int64 is the largest underlying value type that an enum can have" that is not even close to true, in legacy .Net FW you have ulong as well, and in modern .Net you have Int128, UInt128 and the 256 bit value types are also coming soon. Due to unsigned values existing, no matter what type you choose will be a lossy assumption on your part.

@Blindy Actually, no.. You cannot use Int128 as the underlying type of an enum. See SharpLab.

I mean, that's obviously a temporary limitation, and part of the reason why it hasn't been implemented yet is because the .Net JIT engine doesn't currently support arbitrarily sized value types. It's why Int256 isn't out yet, it's waiting for a redesign in the JIT engine to support it first, and then it will apply to everything, including enums.

Also note that you don't even need your assumption in the first place, modern .Net supports generic math: IBitwiseOperators.

@Blindy for generic math you need to know the types at compile time, unless dynamic. The whole point of this answer is to offer an alternative that doesn’t use dynamic, as it is it available everywhere.

Thanks, I think you got it right. I'm giving it a try

Ah, damn, Enum doesn't implement IBitwiseOperators. This type is really the ugly stepchild of .Net isn't it..

Sure, it's called a bitwise OR operation, or |:
    var emptyTank = (eTankComponents)Enum.Parse(enumType, "Empty");
    Console.WriteLine(emptyTank); // Empty
    
    var tankWithBarrel = emptyTank | (eTankComponents)Enum.Parse(enumType, "Barrel");
    Console.WriteLine(tankWithBarrel); // Barrel
    
    var fullTank = tankWithBarrel | (eTankComponents)Enum.Parse(enumType, "wheels");
    Console.WriteLine(fullTank); // Barrel, Wheels

There are many ways of writing the above, from reflection cast to proper types (like my example), to reflection cast to int (if you don't know the enum type statically), to dynamic code even.

That seems to miss the "without knowing the exact enum type" part of the question.

The answer is the same whether or not you know the exact enum type: bitwise OR operation. If you need further assistance understanding the answer, please let me know, or ask a question on SO yourself.

yes, the key point here is "without knowing the exact enum type". I want to find a way to operate the variable object xxxTank without putting eTankComponents into the code, no visible casting upon them.

As mentioned, and I quote, "reflection cast to int (if you don't know the enum type statically)"

In .NET 7, I think you can come up with something like this:
public static class EnumExt {

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, MethodInfo> s_dict = new();
    private static MethodInfo s_orEnumsMethodInfo = typeof(EnumExt)
        .GetMethod(nameof(OrEnums), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    // Unknown type at compile time
    public static object AddFlag(Type type, object enumVal, object flagToAdd) {
        try {
            var methodInfo = s_dict.GetOrAdd(type,ValueFactory);
            return methodInfo.Invoke(null, [enumVal, flagToAdd]);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // TODO: make reflection exception more telling
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static T AddFlag<T>(this T enumVal, T flagToAdd)
    where T : Enum {
        return Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) switch {
            Type t when t == typeof(byte) => OrEnums<T, byte>(enumVal, flagToAdd),
            Type t when t == typeof(sbyte) => OrEnums<T, sbyte>(enumVal, flagToAdd),
            Type t when t == typeof(short) => OrEnums<T, short>(enumVal, flagToAdd),
            Type t when t == typeof(ushort) => OrEnums<T, ushort>(enumVal, flagToAdd),
            Type t when t == typeof(int) => OrEnums<T, int>(enumVal, flagToAdd),
            Type t when t == typeof(uint) => OrEnums<T, uint>(enumVal, flagToAdd),
            Type t when t == typeof(long) => OrEnums<T, long>(enumVal, flagToAdd),
            Type t when t == typeof(ulong) => OrEnums<T, ulong>(enumVal, flagToAdd),
            _ => throw new ArgumentException($"Unsupported underlying type {Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)).Name}")
        };
    }

    private static MethodInfo ValueFactory(Type t) {
        var genMethod = s_orEnumsMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(t, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(t));
        return genMethod;
    }

    private static TEnum OrEnums<TEnum, TUnderlying>(TEnum val1, TEnum val2)
    where TUnderlying : IBitwiseOperators<TUnderlying, TUnderlying, TUnderlying> {
        var firstCast = Unsafe.As<TEnum, TUnderlying>(ref val1);
        var secondCast = Unsafe.As<TEnum, TUnderlying>(ref val2);
        var result = firstCast | secondCast;
        return Unsafe.As<TUnderlying, TEnum>(ref result);
    }
}


Thx, but the point here is without knowing the T. The enum needs to anonymous

@216dark yeah...saw that a bit too late. See updated answer
